# How insert negative values in Gutenberg box-control

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

i'm using [box-control](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/box-control/) component to control the position (top, bottom, left, right) of an absolute positioned element.
I have a problem: box-control doesn't allow negative values.
How can i fix this or, eventually use another components to solve this issue?

Comment: This is not yet possible in Gutenberg core; there's an open issue for this at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/32644

Comment: Thank you, I will follow it!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done through `inputProps` prop. Check below example:

```
<BoxControl
   label={ __('Margin', 'text-domain') }
   onChange={ (margins) => setAttributes({margins}) }
   inputProps={{ min: -300 }}
/>
```